# Cypress cy.visit() throws error in beforeEach() function

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress, mocha.js, e2e-testing

I have created a simple test spec, that contains a few smaller tests. Before each test, cypress has to visit the website that the tests are running on. Therefore, I added the `beforeEach()` funtion to reduce the `cy.visit()` boilerplate-code.
My code so far:

```
import * as fix from '[path]/fixtures.json'

describe('[Spec name]', () => {
     beforeEach(() => {
          cy.visit(fix.url)
     })

     it('[Test name]', () => {
          cy.[Custom command]
          ... other logic
     })

     and so on ...
})
```

But every time the `beforeEach()` function is called, `cy.visit()` throws this error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
```

Then all tests automatically fail, because this error occured in the `beforeEach()` function.

When I tried to remove the `beforeEach()` function and visit the url manually in every single test, `cy.visit()` timed out but the website still loads.
I also checed wether a custom command was modifying `cy.visit()` but that isn't the case.

Comment: What is the value of `fix.url`?

Comment: The website is only hosted locally: "https://www.[subdomain].[name].de"

Comment: And you've verified that the value of `fix.url` in the Cypress tests is what you'd expect it to be? That it is `[subdomain].[name].de`?

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be in the import statement

```js
import * as fix from '[path]/fixtures.json'
```

generally is use like this

```
import fix from '[path]/fixtures.json'
```

The page loader should recognize the file type and parse accordingly, maybe that is not happening correctly with your import statement.

You can easily check with `console.log(fix)`.

Comment: I lean towards this answer as well. I always use import {name} from {path}